# Multiple variable in value

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning JavaScript. What I am doing at the moment is on my contact form trying to pass values.

```
function calculate(){
    var dr1=document.getElementById('numimg');
    var resultdrop=document.getElementById('total');
    resultdrop.value=0;
    resultdrop.value=parseInt(resultdrop.value);
    for(i=0;i<dr1.length;i++)
        if(dr1.options[i].selected)
            resultdrop.value=parseInt(resultdrop.value)+parseInt(dr1[i].value);
}
```

And this is all working fine. Problem appears if with more than one variable that i want to pass to resultdrop.value

```
var dr1=document.getElementById('numimg');
var dr2=document.getElementById('numimg1');
```

Not sure how to sort this out. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why do you try to loop over an array? `dr1` will only contain a reference to one element.

Comment: You give us some setup, but you don't explain what the problem is.  Can you go into more detail about what's actually wrong or not working?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel - this element (numing) is drop down list, its length property actually returns the amount of options in the drop down so the code is indeed valid. @Dom - your code is not passing any value. It's only adding the selected values of "numing" drop down to "resultdrop" value, probably hidden field in the form. To get help, explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have just added the whole function. Basically I'm grabbing value from var dr1 and passing it to var resultdrop. The problem begins when I want to pass more then one var to var resultdrop like var dr1, var dr2...

Comment: @Shadow: Wow, I always used `el.options.length` for that, but you're right (though it's not the most clear notation). Every day is a learning day.

Comment: @Dom - if you need the grand total just repeat the same code you have with "dr1" and replace "dr1" with "dr2" and it will work. If you need to pass each total as separate value, you'll have to add another element called "total2" and have the same logic. Let me know which of those is what you need and I'll post new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say that your HTML probably looks something like this:

```
<select id="numimg" name="numimg">
<!-- Some Options -->
</select>
<select id="numimg1" name="numimg1">
<!-- Some Options -->
</select>
<select id="numimg1" name="numimg1">
<!-- Some Options -->
</select>
```

The problem is that each `id` *must* be unique across your entire HTML document.  If you need to collect multiple DOM elements you can:

1. Use `document.getElementsByTagName` and iterate over that collection, pulling out what you need.
2. Use `document.querySelectorAll` to pull out exactly what you need based on a CSS-style query.
3. Use a library to paper over the differences between browsers for you. (I'd suggest jQuery, but Mootools, Dojo and YUI are a few other good choices.)

But as I said, just a guess -- if we could see your HTML that would help settle the issue.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll works grat for me. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: (Yes, the `ids` repeat -- it was a guess as to how the OP's HTML might look, not a typo -- but thanks!)

Comment: @Dom -- excellent!  Just be aware that `querySelectorAll` does not work in IE7 or below.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't look closely enough at the first line after the code.